# Join subqueries serval times

Tags: join, db2, subquery

I have code that run:

How can I join another query in this subqueries?
I whant a third table that joins with the other tables.
How can I achive this?

```
select *
from 

( select irart, fiben1 as  "Benämning", fisald +irbant as "disp.saldo", sum(irbant) as "Lev.Best"
from triir00
left join trafi00
 on irart = fiart and irfili = fifili

where IRSTYP between 00 and 02 and irlev = '2602688' and irfili = 10 and fihugr = 5
group by irart,fiben1,irlev,fisald,irbant
) as antalLev 

full join

( select raart, fiben1 as "Benämning", raorn9 as "Ordernummer", fisald- raanta as  "Disp.Saldo", sum(raanta) as "Kund.Best"
 from trora00
        left outer join trohu00
         on huorn9 = raorn9
        left join trafi00
         on raart = fiart and rafili = fifili

 where rastyp <= 02 and rafili <> 0 and raotyp = 1 and ralev1 = '2602688' and fihugr = 5
 group by raart,fiben1,raorn9,fisald,raanta
) as antalBest
    on  antalLev.irart = antalBest.raart
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your original query into brackets:

```
select *
from 
(
-- your original query follows below
  select *
  from 
  (
  select columns_for_outer_join, other_columns
  from ...
  ) as antalLev 
  full join
  ( 
  select columns_for_outer_join, other_columns
  from ...
  ) as antalBest on  antalLev.irart = antalBest.raart
-- end of your original query
) a
join (
-- your another sub-query comes here
select columns_for_outer_join, other_columns
from ...
-- end of your another sub-query
) b on <a.columns_for_outer_join = b.columns_for_outer_join>
...;
```

Comment: `join b on <a.columns_for_outer_join are used here>`
I dont understand that one, where do u get the "b"?

can you provide example in your code? with a made u table name etc..? thanks for your answer.

Comment: You said "I whant a third table that joins with the other tables". I got it as follows: "other" tables are those you mentioned in your query, and you need to join the result set produced from them with "third" table (b in my example). If it's not you want, then be more specific about your goal.

Comment: This is exact my goal, but I dont understand what your suggestion do. if you take my query as a example and explain where to put more subqueries would be nice, or do I have to change my query to yours and add my synax?

Comment: See my amended example. If you still don't understand the suggestion, please, provide your example showing what you want exactly.

Comment: I Will one later, but the only thing I whant is to ad another full join. But I Will add a screenshot later. Thank you Mark